# Synergy 1.4.5: How do I get rid of the cursor ("Hourglass"-equivalent in Win7) in the middle of inactive client screens?

Tags: synergy

I'm having an annoying problem with Synergy 1.4.5 (the beta release): When I have a video player (Media Player Classic) active on my client (Win7 Pro x86), and I move my mouse to the server (Win7 Pro x64), the Windows 7 equivalent of the "hourglass" mouse pointer of olden days appears in the middle of the client's screen.

Why is this, and how can I get rid of it?

I'll be trying v1.3.8 tomorrow to see if that fixes it... in the mean time - anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is reported as a bug in the issue tracker: [1623](http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/1623).